# Redux applyMiddleware multiple usage problem with inmutable array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, next.js

I creating a Next.js & Redux app. I using multiple middleware for redux. I have bindMiddleware function for checking development environment and apply development middlewares.

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import promiseMiddleware from "redux-promise-middleware";

const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require("redux-devtools-extension");
    const loggerMiddleware = require("redux-logger");
    return composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware([...middleware, loggerMiddleware])
    );
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware);
};

bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware, promiseMiddleware])
```

My app not working because of this code:

```js
return composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware([...middleware, loggerMiddleware])
);
```

If I use this code instead of the bad code, it won't give an error.

```js
return composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);
```

!!! FIXED !!!

```js
const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require("redux-devtools-extension");
    const { logger } = require("redux-logger"); // edited
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware, logger)); // edited
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require("redux-devtools-extension");
    const { logger } = require("redux-logger"); // edited
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware, logger)); // edited
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware);
};
```